# Can anyone help with this geometry problem?

Tags: geometry

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aINQU.png)

Thanks!

Comment: This post will likely be closed unless you say what you’ve tried and where you’re stuck, FYI

Comment: Please type your question out rather than including a link to an image.

Answer (score 1):

The area of square $S_1$ is $25$ $\text{cm}^2$.

---

Somewhat Related: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2020_AMC_8_Problems/Problem_25

Let $s$ denote the length of the square $S_2$ and $r$ denote the height of rectangles $R_1$ and $R_2$. That means that the height of square $S_3$ is just the sum of the height of the rectangle and the square $S_1$. Therefore, the height of $S_3$ equals $r+s$.

Recall that the height of rectangle $R_2$, denoted by $r$, equals the height of rectangle $R_1$. The height of the entire rectangle ABCD is the sum of the heights of the square $S_3$ and rectangle $R_1$, meaning that the height of ABCD equals $(r+s)+r=2r+s$.

Since squares $S_1$ and $S_2$ have lengths of $r+s$, the width of rectangle ABCD is equal to the sum of the width of square $S_1$, the width of square $S_2$, and the width of the square of $S_3$. Therefore, the width of rectangle ABCD is equal to $(r+s)+s+(r+s)=2r+3s$.

The perimeter of rectangle ABCD is $40$ (given), giving

$(2r+3s)+(2r+s)=20$

$4r+4s=20$

$r+s=5$

Remember that the problem is asking for the area of square $S_1$, and $S_1$ has side lengths of $r+s$, which we just evaluated to be $5$. Therefore the area of the square equals $25$.

NOTE: the answer is actually way easier to figure out if there is a diagram present, so this answer is extra elaborate because there is no diagram present. There are other ways of doing this, too.